# @font-face and wrong letter tracking/spacing

Tags: html, css, font-face, typography

I've encountered a problem using @font-face while building a website.
The font's installed on my PC, I've downloaded it from fontsquirrel.com.

If I use the version that's installed in my PC (Journal), all is well as you can see from the following screenshot:

[image]
<sub>(source: [valeriobulla.it](http://www.valeriobulla.it/normal.jpg))</sub>

However, as soon as I switch to the @font-face version, the letters' tracking (expecially Ts) is different and looks broken:

[image]
<sub>(source: [valeriobulla.it](http://www.valeriobulla.it/error.jpg))</sub>

Here's the code for the @font-face (font-face kit downloaded from font squirrel):

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'JournalRegular';
src: url('journal-webfont.eot');
src: url('journal-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('journal-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('journal-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('journal-webfont.svg#JournalRegular') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
```

And here's the item (a div) styling:

```
#assignment-text {
font-family: Journal, JournalRegular, serif;
font-size: 3em;
text-align: center;
width: 340px;
position: absolute;
top: 200px;
left: 320px;
color: #000;
}
```

Using Journal everything is fine on my PC. Forcing JournalRegular (by commenting Journal) breaks spacing.
I am developing in local. Tested in:
Windows 7 PC (with font installed): Firefox 7, Chrome, Opera, IE9.
Macbook (without font installed): Firefox, Safari.

Is this a known issue? I've searched but I can't seem to find a solution.

Comment: Try using only one `src` URL at a time to see if the problem only manifests with one of the alternative formats? Could be that the format the browser uses doesn't handle horizontally overlapping outlines very well and it's that format that gets picked.

Comment: Ther term you're looking for is "kerning", and I agree with Inerdia that some formats probably don't support it.

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work. Thank you for your comment! @Mark Thank you for your clarification, I am Italian and sometimes I make a bit of confusion when using English technical terms ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've had similar problems with fonts I converted on font-squirrel. One of those times,  going back to the generator and playing on the expert options, notably "Remove Kerning" solved it.

Comment: Well, looks like this IS an answer after all! I previously downloaded a pre-generated font-face kit. Now I know I can customize the options from the Generator. Thank you so much!

Comment: awesome! glad to be of help, then! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have this problem and you can't edit the font - check out my project:

> [Jerning.com](http://jerning.com)

In this case you would be able to do:

```
$('#assignment-text').jerning({
    "Te": -0.1,
    "Th": -0.1
});
```

Here's an example:

```js
$('.with-jerning').jerning("Wo", -0.1);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://jerning.com/js/jquery.jerning.min.js"></script>

<h2 class="without-jerning">Hello World</h2>

<h2 class="with-jerning">Hello World</h2>
```